# Python generate functions from array

Tags: python, function, dry

I want to create multiple functions that have similar structure. And typing them out one by one does not seem to be clever as it obviously violates the do not repeat yourself (DRY) principle.

The situation is such that I have an array `function_names = ["func1", "func2", … , "func10"]`. Additionally I want an if, elif and else statement inside these functions with different actions. These functions are inside a class. The goal is to simplify this structure

```
class MainClass:


    def func1(self):
        if condition_a:
            return action1(parameter1)
        elif condition_b:
            return random_action1(random_parameter1)
        else:
            print("There is something wrong inside func1")

     def func2(self):
        if condition_a:
            return action2(parameter2)
        elif condition_b:
            return random_action2(random_parameter2)
        else:
            print("There is something wrong inside func2")

     # Same structure of functions goes on
```

The conditions `condition_a` and `condition_b` are invariant.

Comment: What is action1 and what is parameter1 ? Where are they being defined? Are they variables of the function?

Comment: you could pass your `action` as another parameter. Functions are first-class citizens in Python and can be passed as parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass the function a function and do a callback :

```
def generic_func(action, random_action, parameter, random_parameter):
    if condition_a:
        return action(parameter)
    elif condition_b:
        return random_action(random_parameter)
    else:
        print("There is something wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write a function which return a function:

```
class MainClass():
    action1 = None
    random_action1 = None
    def mother_func(action, random_action):
        def func(self):
            if condition_a:
                return action(self.parameter)
            elif condition_b:
                return random_action(self.random_parameter)
            else:
                print("There is something wrong inside func")
        return func

    func1 = mother_func(action1, random_action1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary that will map what ever you want to do with `action1` and `random_action1` and your parameters and so on ...

```
class MainClass:

    action1 = lambda x: ()
    random_action_1 = lambda x: ()
    parameter1 = 0
    random_parameter1 = 1

    action2 = lambda x: ()
    random_action_2 = lambda x: ()
    parameter2 = 0
    random_parameter2 = 1

    handler = {
        'func1' : {
            'action': action1,
            'random_action': random_action_1,
            'parameter': parameter1,
            'random_parameter': random_parameter1
        },

        'func2': {
            'action': action2,
            'random_action': random_action_2,
            'parameter': parameter2,
            'random_parameter': random_parameter2
        },
    }

    def gfunc(self, func):
        if condition_a:
            return self.handler[func]['action'](self.handler[func]['parameter'])
        elif condition_b:
            return self.handler[func]['random_action'](self.handler[func]['random_parameter'])
        else:
            print("There is something wrong inside {}".format(func))
```

You can define your `handler` outside of the class and use it as an outsource, and so does your *"parameters"* and *"actions"*.